# Quick question on forest plot [metafor]: changing pre-printed text of used effect size

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am using the function `forest()` of the metafor package to create a forest plot for my meta-analysis. Instead of the pre-printed text "Log Ratio of means" at the bottom and "Log [ROM]" I would like to add the text "Log Response Ratio" and "LnR". I know that the names mean the same effect size but for continuity I would like to use the same name in the whole paper (and plots).
For the summary diamond, there is the possibility to define a text through `mlab="Summary"`. Is there maybe a similar code for the two positions I am talking about? Or is there a way to get rid off the pre-printed text to add my text manually?

This is the code I used with a subset of my data:

```
Modsub <- rma.mv (yi = yi, V = vi,random= list(~ 1|ID_ES, ~ 1|ID_Study), data = subset_data)

windows(height = 80, width = 50)
forest(Modsub,
       slab= subset_data$Author, 
       cex=2, 
       # ylim=c(-3, 95),
       efac= 0.4,
       col= "grey", 
       mlab= "Gesamt-Effektschätzer", 
       header="Autor(en) und Jahr")
```

This is what the plot looks like and in yellow which text parts I would like to change:
[Forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQMDQ.jpg)

Thank you very much for all help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Argument `xlab` for changing the x-axis title and argument `header` can be used to change the headings (make it a vector of two elements). See the documentation:

https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html